# How to include only required files of Extjs5 in Grails without plugin?

Tags: grails, extjs5

I am using Extjs5 and Grails 2.4.4
I have included app.js, ext-all.js and the theme used in the index.gsp. This works well and I get the UI as intended.
After this I included 'pagingtoolbar' and 'checkcolumn' which was missing images. So I included all the images under 'extjs\build\images' folder. 
Now I am getting the images but I feel this is not the right way to include extjs in grails as it leads to many unused files to be included in the source control and hence in production.

So could anyone here please let me know on the right way to include extjs5 in grails?

Comment: I'm not certain how your using Ext Js but you will need to use the Sencha CMD to minify the app to one js file and then include that in grails if you want to only use smallest js file.

Comment: Thanks for you response JeeseRules. I know to use Sencha cmd in a standalone Extjs project and also that it can create separate builds for Development and Production. Is there a way I can use these builds in Grails project?

Currently in the grails project I have added the required CSS, app.js and extjs/build/ext-all.js in index.gsp of grails application to get the UI working. 
Is this the right way to use Extjs5 with Grails? Please help.

Versions used -
Grails 2.4.4
Extjs5